# Component placement and alignment in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following two questions regarding the below web-page:

1. In order to achieve different placement of the Title **1.** element I implemented it **twice** with different visibility.  Was there a way to achieve the same layout without this duplication?
2. On medium and large screens the title **1.** (implemented as `h1` inside `div`) and the box with numbers **3.** (implemented via `thumbnail` in another `div`) are not aligned **at the top**. What causes it and is there a work-around?

I was implementing the following structure:

for `xs` and `sm`:

```
+-----------+
|   1.      |
+-----------+
+------------+    +----------------+
|            |    |                |
|   2.       |    |      3.        |
|            |    +----------------+
+------------+
```

for `md` and `lg`:

```
+------------+     +-----------+   
|            |     |   1.      |
|   2.       |     +-----------+
|            |     +----------------+
+------------+     |                | 
                   |      3.        | 
                   +----------------+
```

**my html**:

```
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4"> 

                <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail"><p>1--<br>2--<br>3--<br>4--<br>5--<br>6--</p></div>
                </div>    



               <div class="col-xs-6">  
                  <div class="col-lg-12">                        
                    <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" >
                    <h1 >Title</h1>
                  </div>

                     <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
                        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                        nostrud exercitation
                        ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </p>
                </div>                      
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> </div>
        </div>        
    </div>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScripts -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle? With the different position of #1, you could try [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering).

Comment: Is this what you are looking for [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/CH5tW/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the float classes (`pull-left`, `pull-right`) like this..

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pull-right"> 
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 pull-left">
        <div class="thumbnail"><p>1--<br>2--<br>3--<br>4--<br>5--<br>6--</p></div>
      </div>    
      <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">  

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
          nostrud exercitation
          ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/125353

***EDIT***

This will move the Title up to the top so that it's aligned with the thumbnail DIV:

```
.title h1 {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

To only apply this on md and lg you'd use..

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .title h1 {
      margin-top:0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it allows to avoid duplication.  What about my 2nd question regarding top alignment?

Comment: For that you'd to remove the top margin from the H1. I updated the demo: http://www.bootply.com/125353

Comment: Almost perfect. How would I limit this margin adjustment to `@media(min-width: @screen-md)` only?  Do I just place all your CSS code inside curly brackets for this media query?

Comment: Yes, see the last @media query in my answer. I also updated the Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/125353